# Visual Studio not launching browser when debugging ASP.Net app

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have Blazor WASM app that is ASP.Net hosted. When I try to debug the server app, Visual Studio does not launch the selected web browser.

When I run the app (F5), the project builds, and VS goes into debug mode, but the browser window never launches.

I have confirmed that Microsoft Edge is the selected browser, and script debugging is disabled.

Other projects on this machine work properly.

My launch settings are unmodified out of the box.

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63525",
        "sslPort": 44395
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "REDACTED": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "dotnetRunMessages": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "",
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7290;http://localhost:5290",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This project launched properly in the past, but suddenly stopped. I don't know what I could have changed.

I have updated to the latest version of Visual Studio (17.3.0), restarted my machine, and deleted the .vs folder. Nothing has worked so far.

Edit: I just noticed that a PowerShell window is opening when I run my app. I get the following error.

```
AppName.exe (process 2372) exited with code -1.
```

I am still not sure what is causing this issue. The code in Program.cs seems to execute without any issue, but when it gets to `app.Run()`, the program exits.

Comment: Options -> projects and solutions -> web projects -> launch browser checked? Also if you try right click on project browse with does it work?

Comment: I don't seen an option for "Launch Browser" in Options. I see "Use 64 Bit IIS", "Warn before running apps with errors", "Stop debugger when browser closes", and "Automatically show data connections from web.confg". I also don't have 'Browse With' in my right click menu. If I select 'Browse With' from the debug toolbar, it builds my app, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Is the app still running despite the browser not launching? Have you tried switching the browser? Have you tried manually typing the address of the running app in a new browser window?

Comment: The app appears to be running, but if I try to go to the url directly, I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. It's possible that the app is closing, but Visual Studio remains in debug mode until I stop it.

I have tried both Edge and Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by a call to `Task.Delay()` in `StartAsync()` of a `IHostedService`.

My intention was to run a background task on a timer, but I wanted to add a delay before kicking off the timer. Because this delay was in StartAsync, it was delaying the entire startup of the app.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your findings with us.

Comment: No problem. I found the issue by reducing Program.cs to the bare minimum, and I noticed that the browser launched as expected. I then systematically started adding code back in until it broke again.

Comment: Half of the questions on StackOverflow could be resolved by applying this exact same approach

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues That's where experience comes in, knowing to start eliminating as many factors as possible until it works again :)